# How memory protection is done without virtual memory?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I was reading OS from Galvin and just had a doubt, how to implement memory protection if the system does not supports virtual memory ? I mean how processes can be given protected address spaces ?

Any new concept or explaination would be awesome...

Comment: i mean how processes can be given protected address spaces ?

Comment: There are many forms of memory protection short of virtual memory, and it rather depends on the particular features of the target system. With pure random-access memory lacking any such mechanism you will be forced to use some form of intepretation which disallows arbitrary code execution and only provides "safe" operations (think a JIT language), or some form of emulation such as dynamic recompilation introducing memory access checks where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[Memory protection on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) shows different methods of memory protection, you should go through that.

If there is no support of virtual-memory, the concept of [Protection keys method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection#Protection_keys) can be used.

Reading it :

> A memory protection key (MPK) mechanism divides physical memory up
>   into blocks of a particular size (e.g., 4 kiB), each of which has an
>   associated numerical value called a protection key. Each process also
>   has a protection key value associated with it. On a memory access the
>   hardware checks that the current process's protection key matches the
>   value associated with the memory block being accessed; if not, an
>   exception occurs.

Comment: what about base registor and limit registor ? i think we can also use that .

Comment: @stackuser - That is another concept used in the segmentation method of memory-protection.

Comment: okk and just one more doubt , This method can be used in multiprocessing systems also ?

Comment: @stackuser - Firstly, no machines have this structure which you asked. It is just an ideal case, which can be extended to any machine, till the core functioning remains the same as in Protection keys method, or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand operating systems, use Galvin to line your cat box and nothing else.

The first key to understanding this problem is to understand the different between logical memory and virtual memory. Sadly, much process and OS documentation conflates the two terms.

Page tables define a continuous, linear, logical address space that maps pages to non-continuous page frames. => Logical memory.

Virtual memory is the process of a using secondary storage (disk) when a page table entry does not map to a physical page frame.

These are two closely related concepts. Virtual memory requires logical memory BUT logical memory does not require virtual memory.

In the latter case, the OS does not use secondary storage to simulate physical memory. When a process accesses a logical page, it must be mapped to a physical page frame, otherwise there is an error (and not a page fault, as in virtual memory).

In the pre-virtual memory days, things were done entirely differently. Then entire processes were swapped in and out (why in Eunuchs, the page file is called the swap partition).This was done using read/write to disk or mapping registers. In those days the address spaces were 64K bytes or smaller so writing a process to disk was not as onerous as it might seem.

In such systems, you got your own 64K or so memory and simply could not access beyond that to get to another process's memory.